# Prevent duplicates from being added to listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, listbox

I'm trying to figure out how to add an `if`/`else` statement so that  when I press the button it doesn't add duplicates to my `listBox`

There's already an if statement but it doesn't work.

Here is the code for the button.

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lstbxResults.Items.Contains(lstbxResults.Items))
    {
        foreach (var Sort in lstbxResults.Items)
            Sorting.Add(LSort);

        Sorting.Sort();
        lstbxResults.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var GSort in Sorting)
            lstbxResults.Items.Add(lSort);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get these following errors
Error 1 Invalid expression term 'else'

Comment: Error 5 Since 'File_Browser_and_Searcher.MainWindow.btnSort_Click(object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Your `if` statement is strange `this.lstbxResults.Items.Contains(this.lstbxResults.Items)` - checks if list is contained in itself.

Comment: Yeah im quite stuck so i pretty much tried everything!!Im not that great a C#

Comment: I think you may be going at this the wrong way. I'm thinking how we could solve that without introducing to many new concepts for you to tackle at this point

Comment: why did you edit away your code?

Comment: You don't need to check `== false`, just put a `!` at the front of the expression..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think base on your code you are trying to sort the data in the listBox and remove the duplicates. 
[image]

```
  private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
    {   
     ArrayList Sorting = new ArrayList();
                if (!this.lstbxResults.Items.Contains(this.lstbxResults.Items))
                {
                    foreach (var fSort in lstbxResults.Items)
                    {
                        Sorting.Add(fSort);
                    }

                    Sorting.Sort();

                    lstbxResults.Items.Clear();

                    foreach (var fSort in Sorting)
                    {
                        if (!this.lstbxResults.Items.Contains(fSort))
                        {
                            lstbxResults.Items.Add(fSort);
                        }

                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**You are missing a closing bracket before `else`**

This is probably causing the error message "Error   1   Invalid expression term 'else' "

**Here's what it should look like**

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{  
    if (!this.lstbxResults.Items.Contains(this.lstbxResults.Items))   
    {  
        foreach (var fSort in lstbxResults.Items)  
        {  
            Sorting.Add(fSort);  
        }  

        Sorting.Sort();

        lstbxResults.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var fSort in Sorting)
        {
            lstbxResults.Items.Add(fSort);
        }
    } // ADD THIS <-----------------------
    else 
    {
       return; // you actually don't need this else statement. Just let the function terminate. 
    }
 // And don't forget to close out your function with another close bracket below
```

**Next**

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396527/127880) on a more efficient way to sort items in a ListBox in ASP.NET:

Comment: His first if does not make sense at all

Comment: True, but the syntax error will at least get him to the next step (which probably belongs in a new question)

Comment: Error 2 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  Im still getting a return null erroe

Comment: What is the type of `Sorting`?

Comment: Since your function returns void, you should not return null; but simply return;

Comment: Im not sure, Im really bad at programming

Comment: In fact... you don't even need to include the else statement (we all have to learn don't worry)

Comment: In very simple terms, what question are you wanting to ask in your if statement?

Comment: just to check if the listbox is already sorted, and not add the item again

Comment: But that is not what you are doing/saying in the code. What are saying (or trying) is "if the items are already sorted, don't sort them again" If you sort you will always add all the items , as you clear them all first and then add them again

Comment: @user2118473 See the link at the bottom of my answer for a more efficient way to approach sorting your listbox

Comment: Yes! @BrianWebster perfect solution, user2118473 you should take his advice and look at that answer.

Comment: @user2118473 Good luck. If you have further errors, it will be best to post a fresh question. Make sure to include any error messages along with your code in your question.

Comment: If it does work please mark Brian's question as the answer, new users tend to forget that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your code - than you are missing closing brace before `else`.

In VS you can easily see where pair of braces are by using `Ctrl+[` when your cursor is positioned over a brace .